# Comparing values of different type

Tags: types, lua, overloading, operator-keyword

At some point of an untouchable program a comparison between two Lua values is done:

```
return a==b;
```

I need to turn this `==` into `>=`, so I've come to the following *hack*:

```
a = { value=5 }
b = { value=2 }

mt = {
  __eq = function (op1, op2) 
    return op1.value >= op2.value
  end
}

setmetatable(a, mt)
setmetatable(b, mt)

print(a == b)
```

And this gives the expected result (`true`). Now, the problem is that `a` and `b` are in different contexts, so I'm not able to do:

```
setmetatable(a, mt)
setmetatable(b, mt)
```

Instead, I can do:

```
mtA = {
  __eq = function (op1, op2) 
    return op1.value >= op2.value
  end
}
setmetatable(a, mtA)


mtB = {
  __eq = function (op1, op2) 
    return op1.value >= op2.value
  end
}
setmetatable(b, mtB)
```

But then, `a` and `b` are of different types and `==` operator returns `false` without even reaching my `__eq` overload.

Any idea on how to achieve what I need?

Comment: Both "a" and "b" are set on isolated contexts, so changes made on global table are dropped. I have no access to the real global table.

Comment: I know Lua 5.1 and 5.2 pretty well, 5.0 not so much. Haven't thought this through for more than a minute. But I have the strong impression that what you're asking won't be possible. Before 5.2, it must be the same function object assigned to a and b's `__eq` for it to ever be invoked. And if you don't have access to any shared environment/table to hold that value, and you can't change the site of the comparison, it looks to me like you're at a dead end.

Comment: @DavidDíaz, ah, that is what is meant by different contexts. I'm not that familiar with Lua...

Comment: If you have access to `require()`, you may be able to store the function in an external module and load it from each context where you need it; each subsequent call to `require()` after the first one will return the same entry in `package.loaded` and so the functions should be identical.

Comment: @furq that's a nice idea. In fact, he could just store an empty table in the external module, and retrieve it by `require mymodule`, then create the function in his Lua code, and save it in the table to be retrieved later. Or he could do this to some table he's already sure is stored in `package.loaded`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've tried on my sandbox and it could be a solution. Unfortunately, I've found that somewhere in the host code there is a:

a = tostring(a)

that renders my hack completely unusable.

Thank you all anyway. I learned a lot from your answers.

Answer (score 3):

Overriding `__eq` works fine with objects of different types under Lua 5.2; however, it should work fine under 5.1 as long as the two metatables both point to the same function, like so:

```
local a, b = { value=5 }, { value=2 }

local function meta_eq(op1, op2) 
  return op1.value >= op2.value
end

setmetatable(a, { __eq = meta_eq })
setmetatable(b, { __eq = meta_eq })

print(a == b) -- true
```

It might also be worth pointing out that in addition to `__eq`, there are `__gt` and `__ge` metamethods which override > and >= respectively.

Comment: I use LUA 5.0. Upgrading is not possible.

Anyway this brings me to the same problem: I have no common place to put the function (or the metatable).